# Using getElementById to duplicate content in page

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know javascript and I have been searching every where for this answer. I would like to duplicate content in my page. The html and content comes directly from a broker.

The result wanted is :

```
Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.
Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.
```

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById('demo').setAttribute('id', 'nextstep');
document.write(elem);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am getting is:

```
Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.
undefined
```

Can somebody help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you want to be using document.write.  I think this is what you're after:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // this gets the element
    var elem = document.getElementById('demo'); 
    // this copies the entire element, including the id
    var newElem = elem.cloneNode(true); 
    // this sets a new id
    newElem.setAttribute('id', 'nextstep');
    // generic way to make sure you insert properly
    var before = elem.nextSibling;
    // there's no insertAfter, only insertBefore, which is why we found the before
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, before);
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BR72b/)

Comment: I could've combined the last two lines into one: `elem.parent.insertBefore(newElem, elem.nextSibling);`, but figured one step per line would be most helpful.  In this specific instance, instead of using `insertBefore`, I could simply have done `document.body.appendChild(newElem);`, but thought it best to use the generic approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Not quite sure why the script does not work on jsFiddle, though. Any thoughts on what I might have done wrong?

Comment: @Joyce Sorry, I should've made a fiddle myself.  There were two errors that I fixed - it should be `elem.parentNode`, not `elem.parent`, and `cloneNode` should have the argument `true` passed to it to make sure it gets all the innerHTML.  I've also appended the (working) fiddle to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know anything about javascript but your answers allowed me to figure things out. This is very helpful.

Comment: @Joyce You're welcome, that's what Stack Overflow is for.  Some links that may help you:  http://overapi.com/javascript/ - lists most of the commands you can use in javascript  http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf - dry reading, but the specification that all javascript clients are supposed to follow

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the `innerHTML` and set it:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
document.write(elem);
```

Beware though, `document.write` is going to overwrite everything..

Comment: Your code did work! My aim is to give the copied elem a new id so that I can style it (adjust the position etc.) not changing the id of the original div. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `elem` to the return value of `setAttribute`, which is undefined as it returns nothing.

Change the code to:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('demo');
elem.setAttribute('id', 'nextstep');
document.write(elem.innerHTML);
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/P8EcL/

This still does not end up with exactly what you want as it is copy of the content of the p tag rather than the tag itself.

[Scott Mermelstein's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19008421/338208) answer is what you want.

Comment: Your code did work! My aim is to give the copied elem a new id so that I can style it (adjust the position etc.) not changing the id of the original div. How would I go about that?

Comment: @Joyce Scott's answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If u need to get this

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
<p id="nextstep">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
```

try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById('demo');
    var newElem = document.createElement('div');
    newElem.innerHTML = "<p id='nextstep'>" + elem.innerHTML + "</p>";
    document.write(newElem.innerHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if u dont want to use document write, use
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newElem);

Comment: This worked! Thank all of you guys so much... This support system is awesome. You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
document.write(elem);
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to set a new id on the original div and expect it to return the HTML, but it's not going to work ;)